# Autogenerate a table of contents in QGIS Print Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am using the Print Composer to create a report. Currently all pages in the report, except the front page, is generated by the Atlas feature.

I would like a table of contents on the bottom part of the front page. In my case there are 11 features that got a page each by the using the Atlas-feature. I would like a table of contents that lists each of these 11 features including the page number that they have in the resulting PDF report.

What if I want to add other parts later on. Is it possible to autogenerate a Table of Contents that includes all parts of the report?

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be to use table in your first page based on your atlas layer data.

To transform an attribute table in a table of content you have differents things to do :

- Delete all the columns
- **Create a column named "page title"** that use the same expression used for your atlas page name.
- **Get the features in the same order**. Your atlas may have a column used to order it. Use the same column to order your table.
- **Add a page number column based on expression** : As you have the same order and you know how many pages you have for each atlas feature, you can calculate the page number for each atlas feature. The formula should look like this : `1 + @row_number` if you have one page before and one page per atlas feature.